# How To Use Inverse Of Markov Inequality?

Tags: probability

This is context of the following problem: Pick a number, uniformly, at random, from $\{1,2,..,10\}$ $n$ times and sum the chosen number starting at $0$ (so each time, sum = sum + whatever random number we chose, with sum initially $0$). What's the probability the sum is at MOST $2n$ using Markov? Let $X$ denote the sum of the numbers.

I have found that $E(X) = \dfrac{11n}{2}$ and $Var(X) = \dfrac{33n}{4}$.

Markov's Generic Inequality is: $$P(X > v) \leq \dfrac{E(X)}{v}$$.

How would I invert this to find $P(X \leq v)$? I think we could define another event $Y_i = 10 - X_i$ and potentially use that to find $X \leq v$ in context of $Y \geq \text{(some quanity)}$, but I am unsure of how to apply this to find the lower bound.

Comment: What about $Q(X\leq v) = 1-Q(X> v)\geq 1-\frac{E[X]}{v}$?

Comment: @ECL, The value I get for $P(X > v$) using $E(X)$ as defined above is 2.75. 1 - 2.75 is an negative number and doesn't work in this case.